# Where is the Kafka bulk producer API

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka as a messaging platform. I need to send a whole bunch of messages to it. I was searching for a bulk api that can take a list of Records, but could not find it in kafka-clients artifact.

Is there a bulk producer api for Kafka in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are the one deciding what signifies a record so splitting up the data into messages has to be done on your side. The Kafka producer supports batching of several messages into fewer sends.

For something more like a bulk loader, there is a recent initiative of something along those lines with the [Copycat framework](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=58851767). Some of this is in [trunk](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/copycat) but it's currently a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I dont understand what this means. The kafka producer api takes a ProducerRecord<Key,Value> type. This means that I wont be able to batch multiple records into the k,v pair, since each key is different. Right? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: There are producer properties 'batch.size' and 'linger.ms' which you can set to control how messages are batched together. 'batch.size' controls the maximum size of a batch of messages before sending and 'linger.ms' is a way to delay the send and wait for more messages to accumulate before sending them as a batch. This is all

Comment: This is all done transparently in the background and you still have to call 'send' on every record separately in your code.